# After Windows 11 22H2 update, wsl command stopped working from PowerShell, still available from cmd.exe

Tags: command-line, powershell, wsl2

Just after the 22H2 update, I opened up WSL to set up a @reboot cron task in my Ubuntu environment. WSL opened without any problems.

I wanted to reboot WSL from PowerShell to make sure my crontab change had worked, and this was the result:

[image: PowerShell screenshot]

This didn't slow me down for long, however, because good-ol' cmd.exe happily obliged. This made me wonder where the `wsl` command lives.

[image: Command Prompt screenshot]

I haven't found a clear way to fix this, but from what I have found I guess the problem has to do with PowerShell favoring 64-bit code over 32-bit... perhaps to the point that it doesn't even want to look in the old Windows\System32 directory for anything?

My system path includes `%SystemRoot%\System32`, and I don't see any sign that PowerShell now uses a different command path, so I'm not sure how to fix this.

**Update:**

Even using a full path to the wsl command doesn't help. It appears the PowerShell is just saying "nuh-uh" about executing this command now.

[image: PowerShell full path screenshot]

And no, uninstalling WSL and reinstalling it doesn't help.

Comment: Have you tried uninstalling and reinstalling WSL?

Comment: @Ramhound, I'd be willing to try that if nothing else works, but I'd rather not lose the current state of my Ubuntu environment by trying that first.

Comment: @Ramhound, I gave un-/re-installing a try. Didn't help, unfortunately. Fortunately, however, I remembered I'm working on a virtual machine, so I just to a snapshot before this experiment, and when it didn't help, restored the old snapshot with my Ubuntu environment intact.

Answer (score 1):

You actually had a good thought on the 32-bit vs. 64-bit that put me on the right track here, just ... backwards!

From the comments, we determined that the 32-bit version of PowerShell was running.  Just a case of the wrong PowerShell version getting pinned to the taskbar, apparently.

It's actually possible to run a 64-bit app (like WSL) from a 32-bit app, but you need to use:

```
C:\Windows\sysnative\wsl.exe
```

That's what (in the comments) gave us the indication that this really *was* the 32-bit PowerShell that was causing the issue.  I've seen this happen in some other Stack Exchange questions when using other 32-bit terminal applications (Hyper.JS IIRC).

Of course, the proper solution, which you certainly reached on your own after we identified the root cause, is to simply use the 64-bit PowerShell.

Comment: What's weird is I don't know how I ended up using the 32-bit PowerShell, and why it didn't matter until I did the 22H2 update. This is a fresh Windows 11 VM I created just a few days ago. I had simply opened PowerShell from the Windows menu and pinned it to the taskbar -- that's it. Why it was the wrong one is baffling.

Comment: @kshetline Right - I'm having trouble "reproducing" that easily myself.

Comment: @kshetline - Windows Terminal can be configured to use 64-bit PS prompt instead of the 32-bit. My suggestion would be to install PowerShell 7.1 64-bit and only use that. Being unable to start WSL within PowerShell isn’t unusual seen it dozens of times over the years since it’s release.

Comment: Definitely agree with @Ramhound on that.  And also forgot to mention Windows Terminal.  You can also set it to be the default Terminal app in Windows 11.  In fact, if this was a new 22H2 install, it would already be set as default.  It's only because it was an upgrade, I believe, that it wasn't.

Comment: Until I ran into this bug, I wasn't even aware of that my 64-bit Windows 11 had both 32-bit and 64-bit PowerShell available. I guess I accidentally picked the 32-bit version the first time I opened PowerShell on this system, and it did everything I needed it to do until the 22H2 update came along. I'm definitely not a PowerShell power user, I've only been using it for WSL setup lately.

Comment: @kshetline Well, same here honestly.  I thought for sure they'd done away with the 32-bit version when I posted that first comment.  But I was wrong.  I guess it can still come in handy from time-to-time.  And yes, it only surfaces when attempting to launch a 64-bit *console* app, it seems.  Running a GUI app (`notepad`) works just fine.  And interestingly enough, that means the latest Store version of WSL also works just fine for me.  You might want to upgrade to it.  A `wsl --upgrade` will probably do it at this point, since you are on 22H2.

Comment: PowerShell 5.1 is installed by default on all supported versions of Windows, Windows has 32-bit and 64-bit of most executables, I can't think of an actual example where that isn't the case (perhaps FIle Explorer, Task Manager, etc). Windows Store version of WSL is more feature enhanced and likely where Microsoft will focus development resources (it recently receive WSLg support on Windows 10).